# JMeter - Aggregate Report with Success response times

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I found Jmeter captures the Response times of a request that had failed in its aggregate report

If i check Successes Check box, i get only success Response times, Samples, Throughput and KB/sec.

And if dint check anything i could see both Successes and failures in all columns

Is there a way in JMeter to get aggregate report with success response times alone but other columns should get total counts (that include both Successes and failure counts) in #Sample, Total errors, Throughput and KB/Sec as it is

[Required Aggregate Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDOuD.png)

At present, i collect data through two simple data writers with checking success check box in one (A) and both in another(B). and load it in two aggregate report listeners and manually copy response times section from replace in csv from B so that i get samples, Errors, Throughput & KB/Sec containing both success and failures requests and response times alone from only successes

Simple data writer config
[SimpleDataWriterConfiguration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcfhN.png)

Please let know any other way to acheive this

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

**Simple option** - add 2 Aggregate Reports:

- Successes only
- Both successes and failures

Take count from second report, and everything else from the first.

However, saving CSV with raw data is more efficient than having 2 Aggregate Reports, and you already have it (almost) so

**Option 2** - save all data into single CSV, and use some tool (linux command line tools, Excel, etc) to sort/parse draw conclusions. You don't need 2 files in this case, since you can always calculate separate totals for success and failure, as well as calculate total of the both from the same file: successes can be filtered by, for example, `OK` in their `responseMessage` field.